# Compiler applies structure padding even though it's not needed

Tags: c, struct, padding, cpu-architecture, memory-alignment

I'm trying to understand how structure padding works in C. In particular, in the Linux x86-64 environment. To this end, I re-arranged the order of the members of a given structure to see if the padding won't be applied when it's not needed. However, when I compiled and run the code printing the size of each structure, padding was applied to both of them, even though the second structure (`struct b`) has its members arranged in such a way that contiguously storing them in memory won't result in one of them occupying multiple word blocks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct a {
    int ak; 
    char ac; 
    char* aptr; 
};

struct b {
    char* bptr;
    int bk;
    char bc;
};



int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(struct a));
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(struct b));
}
```

Output:

```
16

16
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The largest member of `struct b` (or more accurately, the member with the widest alignment requirements) has 8 byte alignment, so the size of the struct needs to be a multiple of 8 so that an array of that struct will have its members properly aligned.

So `struct b` will have 3 bytes of padding at the end.

Comment: Wording nitpick: in this case it's the largest member that also has the highest `alignof()`, but a `char*` member would still be the most-aligned member if there was an `int arr[16]` member.  Or a `__int128 foo __attribute__((aligned(1)))` under-aligned member, if that works like it does with typedef.